# mssql error not thrown on nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
select *
from OuterQueryTable
where OuterQueryColumn in (select OuteryQueryColumn
                           from InnerQueryTable)
```

OuterQueryColumn does not exist in InnerQueryTable.  Why does this result in a successful query instead of an error?  What is the expected output from the inner query?

Comment: What do  you mean by "result in a successful query" if the where condition is not met then you should get 0 rows back not an exception.

Comment: An error will be thrown if your query isn't well formed, here the query is correct and there is no result corresponding to your request. No error but no result ;-)

Comment: No it does not return an error.   And it returns rows.

Comment: @sammarcow provide us the tables structure

Comment: If you just run `select OuteryQueryColumn from InnerQueryTable` what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column exists in the inner scope due to the outer scope, i.e this will not compile:

```
select *
from OuterQueryTable A
where OuterQueryColumn in (select B.OuteryQueryColumn
                           from InnerQueryTable B)
```

Your initial query is logically equivalent to:

```
select *
from OuterQueryTable
```